# bash script: how to display output in different line

Tags: bash, shell

i'm trying use one line of code to solve a problem

```
echo $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer $1  | sed 's,\.\/,,g')
```

this will print out all the file in current folder that are newer than the input file. But it prints out in one single line:

```
file1 file2 file3 file4....
```

how can i display each file name in a single line like:

```
file1
file2
file3
...
```

This seems to be a very simple but i've been searching and have no solution.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of the `echo` and the `$(...)`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer "$1" | sed 's,\.\/,,g'
```

If you have GNU find you can replace the `sed` with a `-printf` action:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer "$1" -printf '%P\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

pipe it to `tr`:

```
... | tr " " "\n"
```